# How to re-mail emails rather than forward them?

Tags: email, printing, cloud

I'm trying to **automatically forward *certain* emails** - and their attachments - to a mailserver that delivers emails based on the "To: " header.

Here's what I've tried:
- "forwarding filters" in gmail
- adding the printer to a "google group" as a mailing list subscriber
- forwarding from Hotmail/Outlook
- setting up mail filters in Mozilla Thunderbird and forwarding the incoming mail with those

Out of those four ideas, the only one that correctly remailed my emails (with "To: " header set correctly) was Thunderbird. Thunderbird isn't ideal as it is not easy to maintain the filtering/forwarding configuration.

**How can I actually *re-mail* emails to a specified address, and not just forward them??**

Thanks everyone.
Yes I'm open to "you are asking the wrong question, here is a better solution than what you want", or other suggestions, if you really believe that. I hope I stated my reasons clearly enough.

Comment: edited question to try to make it on-topic and keep it relevant. Please do comment if my attempt has been a failure.

Comment: What broken mail server is this that pays more attention to the `To:` header rather than the envelope recipient list?! My suggestion would be to use a mail server that is actually SMTP compliant. [RFC 5321 section 4.1.1.3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.3)

Comment: @Michael well maybe a script behind the server rather than the mta itself:  
    ;; ANSWER SECTION:
hpeprint.com.           389     IN      MX      10 onramp02.hpeprint.com.  
`telnet onramp01.hpeprint.com 25
Trying 15.201.184.201...
Connected to onramp01.hpeprint.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 hpeprint.com ESMTP Postfix
`

Comment: You say in the question that "[the] mail server delivers emails based on the 'To' header". SMTP specifies that mail should be delivered based on RCPT TO commands (AKA "envelope recipient"). [RFC 5321 section 3.3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-3.3) specifies that `MAIL` and `RCPT` commands *must* come before `DATA`, and it's not before `DATA` that the SMTP server even sees the headers.

Comment: What that means is that you're either dealing with a server that does not properly implement SMTP, or you are approaching this from the wrong angle with your statement in the question's opening paragraph.

Comment: Thirteen years ago, I went to a school where we were allowed internet access but not allowed to read or send emails. For some reason we were allowed to use telnet, so what I would do is telnet out to an SMTP server (truth is stranger than fiction) and compose my emails by hand. I'd sometimes put misleading "To:" and "From:" data in my email, knowing that it didn't really matter. Somehow, when deciding how to process incoming emails, onramp01/02 seriously does disregard the envelope recipient and work solely based on the "To:" field. Who knows why? It's quite frustrating.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, the server is postfix (which should be fine) - it's technically whatever is processing the emails after postfix (a la procmail?) which is noncompliant. ........... I suspect that you're right - that it's not properly implementing SMTP _AND_ that I'm approaching it from the wrong angle. Maybe it's such a niche experience that a thunderbird / procmail style solution really is as good as I'm going to get :-(

Comment: I should point out that I can't read emails at the recipient address per se, and certainly do not administer the server that I'm sending to